# Google Query For Dates in Last 30 Days

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to figure out how to do a google query for dates in the last 30 days.  I'm using a wordpress plugin that lets you display spreadsheet data and do queries.

Here is the current working query

```
query="SELECT B,N,E,G,H,I WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks'"
```

And here is the one I'm trying that just doesn't work.

```
query="SELECT B,N,E,G,H,I WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' and G>NOW()-30"
```

This is inside a shortcode in WordPress, so I don't think that the formatting is exactly the same as in Google.  Here is a working example:

```
[gdoc key="https://docs.google.com/a/justinhandley.com/spreadsheets/d/15q2H_X0nohUJs8vgZ6NFiHrtU5lBKrEQLM1dJoQgB6E/edit" gid="2078888428" class="no-datatables" query="SELECT B,N,E,G,H,I WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' "]
```

Based on answers below, I have tried...

```
[gdoc key="https://docs.google.com/a/justinhandley.com/spreadsheets/d/15q2H_X0nohUJs8vgZ6NFiHrtU5lBKrEQLM1dJoQgB6E/edit" gid="2078888428" class="no-datatables" query="SELECT B,N,E,G,H,I WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' "]
```

Which works (but doesn't filter by date) and can be seen at

http://leibovitvrnewsletters.com/portfolio-test-1/

```
[gdoc key="https://docs.google.com/a/justinhandley.com/spreadsheets/d/15q2H_X0nohUJs8vgZ6NFiHrtU5lBKrEQLM1dJoQgB6E/edit" gid="2078888428" class="no-datatables" query="('VR Platinum'!A:N, "SELECT * WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' AND G >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ") "]
```

Which copies the query below, but doesn't work (doesn't sort by anything, seems to return entire list of everything) and can be seen at

/portfolio-test-2/

```
[gdoc key="https://docs.google.com/a/justinhandley.com/spreadsheets/d/15q2H_X0nohUJs8vgZ6NFiHrtU5lBKrEQLM1dJoQgB6E/edit" gid="2078888428" class="no-datatables" query="SELECT B,N,E,G,H,I WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' AND G >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' "]
```

Which just totally breaks, and can be seen at

/portfolio-test-3/

Any help putting this together is much appreciated.

Comment: For clarification, this is not inside the google spreadsheet.  To give an example of the full working codeblock: 

    [gdoc key="https://docs.google.com/a/justinhandley.com/spreadsheets/d/15q2H_X0nohUJs8vgZ6NFiHrtU5lBKrEQLM1dJoQgB6E/edit" gid="2078888428" class="no-datatables" query="SELECT B,N,E,G,H,I WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' "]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I finally got this to work as a combination of forces.  The plugin author gave me some great advice here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/and-and-quotes-in-a-query?replies=4#post-6894935

Which was - why try to be so complex in the plugin itself?  Instead, why not do the heavy lifting in Google.

So, I used the query provided by @JacobJanTuinstra

```
=QUERY('VR Platinum'!A:N, "SELECT * WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' AND G >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ")
```

In a new spreadsheet in the Google doc.  In fact, I took out the stock type filter and just filtered by date.

```
=QUERY('VR Platinum'!A:N, "SELECT * WHERE AND G >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ")
```

Then, I was able to use my exact same query that was currently working, and just switch out the spreadsheet ID.  So in the plugin I still used

```
query="SELECT B,N,E,G,H,I WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks'"
```

and just queried against the spreadsheet I created based on the Google query above, and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following modification.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA, "SELECT B WHERE A='Exit' AND G >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ")
```

### Reference

[Google Spreadsheet: Count values from last 30 days](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51509/google-spreadsheet-count-values-from-last-30-days)

Comment: This gave me an error.  What was actually tried was adding G >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' to the end of the query block I just added on to the end of the original question.  I'm wondering if it is a quotes issue - with nesting like this do they need to be commented out?

Comment: @JustinHandley This worked for me: `=QUERY('VR Platinum'!A:N, "SELECT * WHERE A='Exited Positions Bullish Stocks' AND G >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ")`

Comment: I have been trying to get that to work.  I've done three pages...

Comment: Please see the new full ammended questions for examples.